# how to inner join three tables and get count

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

```
members (id, name, surname, usr_img)

user_uploads (imgID, user_id, filename, description, up_time)

img_likes (likeID, img_id, user_id)
```

I need to get all from user_uploads, and using the img_id, get uploader info from members and make 2 counts in the img_likes table (check if user_id (from session variable) and img_id exists and get the img total likes).

```
SELECT user_uploads.* AS uu, members.*, COUNT(img_id, user_id) AS usr_liked, COUNT(img_id) AS total_likes
FROM user_uploads
INNER JOIN members AS m ON m.id = uu.user_id -- owner info
INNER JOIN img_likes AS il ON il.img_id = uu.imgID AND il.user_id = ? -- check if logged in user already liked
INNER JOIN img_likes AS ilt ON ilt.img_id = uu.imgID -- total likes
GROUP BY img_id, user_id
ORDER BY up_time DESC
```

I don't need to get nothing from img_id, just count the number of rows. I don't know if an inner join is necessary, maybe to specify the user_id?

and to get the counts:

```
$usr_liked = row['usr_liked'];
$total_likes = rwo['total_likes'];
```

Will that work?

EDIT: add new query:

```
SELECT
    user_uploads.*,
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM members m
        WHERE m.id = user_uploads.user_id
    ),
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM img_likes t
        WHERE t.img_id = user_uploads.imgID AND t.user_id = ?
    ) AS user_likes,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM img_likes t
        WHERE t.img_id = user_uploads.imgID
    ) AS total_likes
FROM user_uploads
ORDER BY up_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    uu.*, 
    m.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(t.*)
        FROM img_likes t
        WHERE t.img_id = uu.imgID AND t.user_id = ?
    ) AS user_likes,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(t.*)
        FROM img_likes t
        WHERE t.img_id = uu.imgID 
    ) AS total_likes
FROM 
    user_uploads AS uu
    INNER JOIN members AS m ON 
        m.id = uu.user_id
ORDER BY
    uu.up_time DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Due to some errors I modify it. I was getting an error if I joined the members table, so I just added it like a subquery too. But it's giving an error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @ChazyChaz: the errors already tells you everything, subquery should return only one result. Return the members inner join like you have before. p.s. I have edited my answer to have full query.

Comment: Yes, my fault I forgot to rename the table. Thanks, I'ts working!